# NSFileManager removeItemAtPath does not remove file

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

So, I searched the net and stackoverflow, checked the threads mentioned above this text box as possible already asked questions but the answers or tips couldn't help me because the code at first was OK and there was nothing wrong with it, it shouldn't be, because it is just not that hard. But for some reason I can not delete a earlier created file. The code:

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true);
NSString *dbFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dirPaths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"]];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbFile];
NSLog(@"Path to file: %@", dbFile);
NSLog(@"File exists: %d", fileExists);
NSLog(@"Is deletable file at path: %d", [fileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:dbFile]);
if (fileExists) {
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbFile error:&error];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); }
    else { NSLog(@"probably deleted the file!"); }
}
```

The output:

```
2014-09-15 17:29:25.058 test[13862:60b] Path to file: /var/mobile/Applications/BB708129-C504-4E84-9C08-DF4ACE1369DC/Documents/database.db
2014-09-15 17:29:25.060 test[13862:60b] File exists: 1
2014-09-15 17:29:25.061 test[13862:60b] Is deletable file at path: 1
2014-09-15 17:29:25.063 test[13862:60b] probably deleted the file!
```

But every time I run the code It says the file exists and does not get deleted. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have code that creates the file each time? And after deleting, add a call to `fileExistsAtPath:` to confirm it is gone.

Comment: Its likely the issue lies outside the scope of `NSFileManager`. As @rmaddy mentioned, look over the code that is responsible for creating the file and make sure its not recreating the file after it is deleted (ex: opening and SQLite database connection will create the file if it doesn't exists).

Comment: Alright, you were right. I am working with sqlite3 and the function sqlite3_open() creates a db file if it does not exists. I had a db initializer/creator and a select function. I was using the select function to check if the file and rows inside still exist. Inside there was also a sqlite3_open() function... Strange thing though, the file variable for the function (dbpath = [dbFile UTF8String];) was commented, so I thought that would stop creating the file. Thank you both very much!